# ROS not calling callbacks fast enough

Tags: ros, callbackqueue, callback, callbacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

EDIT:

Here's a basic [talker/listener example](https://github.com/anuppari/basic_package) that reproduces the problem, if anyone else wants to try it. The talker is sending msgs of type `gazebo_msgs::LinkStates`, at 1kHz. When less than 5 links are in the message, the listener callback is called at 1kHz. When there are more than 5 links, the listener callback only gets called at ~170 Hz.

---

Original Post:

There is something wrong with how ROS is calling subscriber callbacks at a much slower rate than msgs are being published. Here's a minimal example.

```
class DataHandler
{
private:
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::Publisher test_pub;
public:
  DataHandler() { test_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>("test",10); }
  void callback(const gazebo_msgs::LinkStatesConstPtr& msg)
  {
    test_pub.publish(geometry_msgs::PoseStamped());
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "gazebo_to_ros");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  
  DataHandler callbacks;
  ros::Subscriber linkSub = nh.subscribe("gazebo/link_states",1,&DataHandler::callback,&callbacks);
  
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

The topic "gazebo/link_states" is being published to at 500 Hz (using `rostopic hz` at the command line). The code in the callback takes a trivial amount of time to run (using [std::chrono](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/), less than 1ms => can run >1000Hz). The topic "test" is only being published to at ~70 Hz. Time between callback calls fluctuates between 1e-5 s and 0.04s, => 100kHz to 25 Hz, yielding an average of ~70 Hz.

Resource monitor shows cpu usage at less than 50%. Even setting high priority for this process changes nothing, so I don't think its a bottleneck in the hardware.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with ROS Kinetic. Anyone have any idea at what I should look at next to help troubleshoot? Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253942/ros-not-calling-callbacks-fast-enough/) by [anuppari](https://answers.ros.org/users/5082/anuppari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2017-02-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-02-06**:
ROS may be dropping messages in the subscriber queue. You may want to enable topic statistics and look for dropped messages in [rqt_graph](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graph), and then try increasing the subscriber queue length.

**Comment by [anuppari](https://answers.ros.org/users/5082/anuppari/) on 2017-02-07**:
I made a simple [talker/listener package](https://github.com/anuppari/basic_package) to test this. When I just run the the talker and listener nodes with nothing else running, both run fine at 1kHz, and even at 10kHz. If I also have my simulation running in parallel, then I get msg drop.

**Comment by [anuppari](https://answers.ros.org/users/5082/anuppari/) on 2017-02-07**:
However, they are communicating on separate topics, so why would the simulation interfere? My CPU usage is still around 50%.

**Comment by [felix](https://answers.ros.org/users/154/felix/) on 2020-01-27**:
In simulation, my experience is that time/clock is managed by the simulator and you get a lot of overhead because of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried using the [noTcpDelay](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1TransportHints.html#a03191a9987162fca0ae2c81fa79fcde9) option?

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anuppari](https://answers.ros.org/users/5082/anuppari/) on 2017-02-07**:
Based on [Dirk](http://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/)'s suggestion, I tried the [noTcpDelay](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Transport_Hints) transport hint, and that seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks!